# Android make Dialog fullscreen with status bar showing

Tags: android, dialog

I want to make a dialog box with full screen but not hiding the status bar.

If use style `Theme_Light_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen`, the dialog box occupies the whole screen.

If use style `Theme_Material_Light_NoActionBar_TranslucentDecor`, it seems working but the top of the dialog box actually is becoming transparent. I can make it better by enquiring the status bar height and add top padding to my dialog layout. This solution seems works fine, except it does not work if I attached an animation to it.

I am very confused why Google make the dialog box so complicated to use, and if I am doing correctly to make a full screen dialog box here?

Answer (score 13):

Just use **THEME_BLACK_NoTitleBar**
Worked For me!!!

Comment: I could not find this theme, on androidx at least

Comment: I want to make statusbar color white, and using this or light theme.. it keep showing black coloured statusbar

Comment: I used Theme_DeviceDefault_NoActionBar

Answer (score 6):

It maybe too late but for the sake of others who have the same problem :

```
    dialog = new dialog(context,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use **android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar**

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context,
                   android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar);
```

[Example screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsVtI.png)

Answer (score 2):

I have found a snipplet from a blog, after a few tries i found that i have to use `Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen` in constructor, together with the snipplet during `onCreate`. now my dialog is fullscreen and shows status bar.

```
public YourCustomDiag(Activity act){
    //step 1, required. to stretch the dialog to full screen
    super(act, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout);
    KeepStatusBar();
}

//step 2, required
private void KeepStatusBar(){    
    WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
    attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
}
```

[this is the source where i found the snipplet](http://blog.thevery.info/2010/11/showhide-status-bar-in-fullscreen.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()),
            android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

This will use the primaryDarkColor for the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use :

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ctx, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar);
```

This will display the status bar and remaining dialog will be full screen

Answer (score -1):

Just use your own application theme style. It will come along.
example: Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.YOUR_THEME_STYLE);
[themes/style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaDzs.png)